# How to access plugin in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I am new in cakephp, I want to call the plugin via the URL. Here is URL of

```
http://testproject.local/PluginName/ControllerName/ActionName
```

When I Run this URL at that time I found "Missing Controller" error.

```
Missing Controller
Error: <ControllerName>Controller could not be found.

Error: Create the class <ControllerName>Controller below in file: `app/Controller/<ControllerName>Controller.php`
```

It's showing me

```
`Exception Attributes: array ( 'class' => 'PracticeFusionController', 'plugin' => NULL, )`
```

Here is my routes.php

```
Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'home'));
/**
 * ...and connect the rest of 'Pages' controller's urls.
 */
Router::connect('/Pages/*', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display'));

Router::connect('/gods/:action/*', array('plugin' => 'nova', 'controller' => 'gods'));
Router::connect('/gods', array('plugin' => 'nova', 'controller' => 'gods'));

Router::parseExtensions('json', 'xml');

Router::mapResources('events');

Router::connect('/<pluginName>', array('plugin' => '<pluginName>', 'controller' => '<ControllerName>'));
```

Comment: Please include your routes in the answer. It looks like you haven't set those up properly.

Answer (score 1):

You can only load/open Plugin routes if you actually loaded the plugin in your project's bootstrap. You don't need to include a plugin route in your core app's routes.php. If you want to add plugin specific routes, you can load the plugin specific routes file, using the `routes` option. Note that by default all `/plugin/controller/action` routes are already routed properly, you don't need a separate routes file for that.

So, in your core app's app/Config/bootstrap.php, add:

```
CakePlugin::load('YourPlugin', array('routes' = true));
```

The routes from your plugin's Config/routes.php will then be loaded and can be used.
More details on this can also be found in [the documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/plugins/how-to-use-plugins.html).

Answer (score 0):

If above solutions does not works, please load plugin like CakePlugin::load('YourPlugin', array('routes' => true)); Please note array passed is : array('routes' => true)